# roslaunch stop if yaml doesn't exists

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, rosparam, load

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working on autonomous cars and I need a specific performance of roslaunch. I am working with a webserver and I need to know if a vehicle exists in the webserver. In this case I write a yaml file to save the vehicle_ID and continue working. Afterwards, I reset everything and roslaunch again the file. If the vehicle_id.yaml file exists, I load over roslaunch with rosparam command "load"

My problem is that if the vehicle_id.yaml doesn't exists, roslaunch give me an error and stop the whole roslaunch.

This is my roslaunch:

```
<launch>        
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find webserver_client)/config/vehicle_id.yaml"/>
    <node name="webserver_client" pkg="webserver_client" type="webserver_client" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

Is there a possibility to ask if the yaml file exists and if not, don't load the parameters?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236002/roslaunch-stop-if-yaml-doesn%27t-exists/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, you can not do this directly in the roslaunch. However, you can add an  tag to the ros launch, and then use the  and/or  attributes to either read or not the .yaml file

Should be something like this:

```
<launch>
      <!-- ros_args -->
      <arg name="foo" default="true"/>
     <group if="$(arg foo)">
         <rosparam command="load" file="$(find webserver_client)/config/vehicle_id.yaml"/>
     </group>
     <node name="webserver_client" pkg="webserver_client" type="webserver_client" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

Then you can pass the argument to the roslaunch from command line after checking whether or not the file exists.

You can find more info on that here

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg

and here

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools

Regards,

Mario

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on 2016-06-06**:
Thank you for your answer. I solve it directly with a fake vehicle_id.yaml that always has to be there and then if there is "empty" message, I overwrite it with the correct id. I appreciate your help.